# In Adjacency matrix I want replace with its values which is given the other matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

My question is that, I have an adjacency matrix like

INPUT:

```
       1 2 3 4 5 
A = 1 [0 1 1 0 1]
    2 [1 0 1 0 1]
    3 [0 1 0 1 0]
    4 [1 0 1 0 1]
    5 [0 0 1 0 0]
```

The above matrix is to create a graph or generate a spanning tree, and another Matrix is (Which represents the value of edges in the graph)

INPUT:

```
B = [0  22 33 0  44]  
    [55 0  66 0  77]
    [0  11 0  22 0]
    [11 0  88 0  55]
    [0  0  55 0  0]
```

I want replace all the elements of `A` with the help of `B` Matrix where ever 1 are present in matrix `A`, which means the **output** should be

```
A = [0  22 33 0  44]  
    [55 0  66 0  77]
    [0  11 0  22 0]
    [11 0  88 0  55]
    [0  0  55 0  0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` only contains 0 and 1, I suggest:

```
A = B.*A;
```

However, with the samples you have provided above, `A = B` should work just fine (but I guess the examples are not representative.

Comment: >> A = [0 1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]

A =

     0     1     1
     1     0     1
     0     1     0

>> B = [0 11 22; 33 0 44; 0 55 0];
>> A = B.*A;
>> A = B.*A

A =

           0         121         484
        1089           0        1936
           0        3025           0
This is what I got sir                                                                  I want to replace the elements with the value of B                                                                     Thanks for your help...

Comment: @user3226283: You multiplied twice! Try again, it should be correct. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
 % first make A into logical matrix, and the select from B values where A == 1;
 A = B(logical(A));
```

Comment: >> A = [0 1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]

A =

     0     1     1
     1     0     1
     0     1     0

>> B = [0 11 22; 33 0 44; 0 55 0];
>> A = B(logical(A));
>> A = B(logical(A))

A =

     0
    33
     0
    11
     0

Comment: @user3226283 So its good or bad? Its not clear what you really want to achieve. Maybe edit question with new examples.